# Developing in Visual Studio 2010 and Sharepoint 2007. Using new SPSite throws errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2007

I'm re-writing a console application using Visual Studio 2010. The original application was written using Visual Studio 2008 and works OK, but has no tests associated with it. Hence, the idea of re-writing it with tests.

Both applications are working with a Sharepoint 2007 site.

The project compiles but when I try and run it the code below is throwing errors.

```
        SPSite spsite = null;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
            spsite = new SPSite("http://sharepointdev");
        });

        return spsite;
```

I'm running this on Windows Server 2008. I've set the platform target of the build to be x86 (this is in the properties of my project) and in Security I've checked that this is a full trust application. I'm also running the project as an administrator. I've also set the .NET Framework to be 3.5

Is it just a case that SharePoint 2007 just doesn't want to play with Visual Studio 2010, or is there something else I've not yet considered?

I've tried searching on the web and stackoverflow but all the articles I've seen deal with trying to get Visual Studio 2010 to work with Sharepoint 2010.

The exact error I get is 'Object reference not set to an instant of an object' with the debugger high-lighting the SPSecurity call.

If I just use this code

```
using(SPSite spsite = new SPSite("http://sharepointdev")){
```

Then I get a FileNotFoundException, which isn't exactly true! I've got plenty of applications that do find a site using that URL. What I suspect the error message is trying to say is that my 2010 application is not being allowed to access the site, but I've not found any clues as to why that should be.

Any clues, hints or suggestions gratefully accepted.

**EDIT**

I've lifted the code from my VS 2010 project and dropped it into a new VS 2008 project and it ran straight-away.

**FURTHER EDIT**

I created a simple little console application in VS 2010. By default it uses .NET Framework 4, I had to set this to .NET Framework 3.5. I also set the platform target to be 'Any CPU' and it works. This makes me wonder if there is an issue with the Test Project associated with my first application?

I re-created the console application but this time without a Test Project associated with it (the test project was a class library and worked with NUnit). It ran with no problems. I guess the problem lies within the test project and something there that the solution doesn't like. Probably there's a build there it doesn't like

Comment: Unrelated to your specific problem: In your first code listing you're creating a new SPSite object and returning it to the caller. I really hope you're disposing this object when you're done with it. You will get a lot of leaked memory and bad performance (the app pool recycles from reaching its memory threshold) if you don't take care to do this.

Comment: Hi Eric, Not to worry I am disposing that object. The first bit of code comes from a function, which is called from within a using block. Thank you for pointing out a potential problem though.

Comment: Weird - was the test project targeting .NET 4.0?

Comment: Hi Eric. Initially, yes it was but I switched it to .NET 3.5 and still got that error. The only things I'm using in the test project is NUnit and Rhino.Mocks. I marked your response as the answer since it helped me a great deal and will help anyone else who comes across this question. If I get chance I'll see what happens when I add a test project to the re-created app and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR; answer: Switch to Any CPU build - don't choose x86.

I've run into this problem before with a console utility. I got the same FileNotFound error but it's referring to the DLL, not your SharePoint site. Digging a bit I discovered a deeper error of BadImageFormat and realized it was complaining about a DLL or EXE. I guessed it was due to the linking from x86 to MSIL. There's a lot of things that have to happen to marshal calls between the two and I guess it led to an incompatibility. When I switched it (and verified all my support library projects) built to MSIL/Any CPU the application worked with no problems and no other changes.

I use Visual Studio 2010 to develop for SharePoint 2007 all day for a long time now and the only problems I've encountered aren't related to that combination. More often than not it's a quirk of a 3rd party add-on I'm using. For almost all of my development I start with the WSP Builder templates but they are buggy and have a few quirks you have to work around (some severe enough to take down your SharePoint server) so I don't blame VS 2010 directly.

Comment: Hi Eric, I switched back to 'Any CPU' and now I get 'Error trying to run project. Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. I think this is why I'd gone down the route of changing the build to x86. I'm going to check a custom DLL that I'm using. I suspect (and my suspicions are encouraged by your comments in your second paragraph) that might be the culprit. I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi, I removed the custom DLL, I was only using one method in it, so I've pulled that code into my app, just to help remove a candidate. I'm still getting the 'attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format'. I'm referencing the Microsoft.Sharepoint DLL, this is version 12 and has runtime version v2.0.50727. Could that be the offender?

Comment: No, SharePoint wouldn't be running if that was corrupt or missing and you have to have a reference to it for any object model code you write against SharePoint. Bad Image Format is almost always due to x86 vs MSIL libraries and build targets. I've always been able to resolve this with just ensuring everything was com... wait - you don't have any .NET 4.0 assemblies you're referencing, do you? That will also do it if I remember correctly.

Comment: Hello. I mentioned Microsoft.Sharepoint in case it needed to be version 14. Just a guess. I don't have any alternatives to it on my server anyway. I'm not aware of referencing any NET 4.0 Assemblies. They are all fairly basic. I'll check and get back to you. Thanks again for your help Eric, much appreciated.

Comment: Version 12 is SharePoint 2007/MOSS. Version 14 is SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Hi Eric, These are the DLLs I'm referencing, Microsoft.Sharepoint(NET 3.5), System (NET 2), System.Core (3.5), System.Data (2.0) System.Data.DataSetExtensions (3.5), System.Xml(2.0) and System.Xml.Linq (3.5). All pretty standard I would have thought. The solution does contain a test project that uses NUnit, but the main project is not dependent on the test project.

Comment: You're sure that after you switched from x86 and rebuilt, it was successful and deployed correctly? Try clearing the GAC of all versions of your built DLL and deploy again.

Comment: Hi Eric. I'm not deploying it to the GAC. I'm just running it in debug mode in Visual Studio. It's something I've done previously using VS 2008 with no problems

Comment: Oh right, sorry - you're running a CLI that should be interfacing. And you're running it from VS on the same box where SharePoint is installed, yes? And you're sure you're running the latest version of the executable not compiled against x86?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm sorely tempted to move it all from VS 2010 back to VS 2008 and try it, see what that does.

Comment: Hi Eric, I've just looked at this again. If I set the 'Platform target:' to be Any CPU in the Build window within the project's properties then I'm not able to run the project. I get an error message. However at the top of the Build Window where the configuration options are displayed I only have one choice for the platform, which is Active (x86)

Comment: Hiya. It's an error from Visual Studio. The exact text is 'Error while trying to run project: Could not load file or assembly 'DansProject' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'  I really appreciate your tenacity and patience with this problem.

Comment: There aren't any more detailed messages in the Output window that maybe points to WHICH assembly or dependency it doesn't like?

Comment: Hi Eric, sadly no. And the error doesn't appear in the Output window. It builds but then when I click debug  I get this message. There are no errors, warnings or information after I build either. You might notice in my edits that I've got a simple little app running in VS 2010 so I'll try and expand that and see where it complains. I suspect it might have something to do with having an NUnit Test project as part of the solution, although I don't see how that could affect the main project.